# Show when suggested edit was rejected

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, timestamps, rejected-edits

When suggested edit is approved, the time of approval is visible. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/341671):

> [image]

All good. However, when suggested edit is rejected, such time stamp is missing. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/341646):

> [image]

Think it will be nice to add the time of rejection as well, unless there is a reason for the current behavior?

I can find the time of rejection by going to one of the rejectors' profile and find the match in their *reviews* tab so it's not like that information is private or secret.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now implemented as part of the new review system. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/794093):

> [image]